# Convert values in array to date objects jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have array I'm getting from calling a .net controller.

I'm getting these values for dates:

`/Date(1445256000000)/` and `/Date(1445256900000)/`

Instead of that I want to be able to get proper date values.

Now since I have array of objects I want to be able to update them in the array before sending them to the view.

This is what I have:

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Driver/GetDriverTrips',
            params: { id: id }
        }).
        success(function (data) {
            var startDate= new Date(data[0].StartTime.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
            alert(myDate);

        });
```

So this conversion works properly but the thing is that I want to loop through all the same objects in the array, do the conversion and then again save it in the array.

Is there any function I can do that?

Comment: like... ? a for loop?

Comment: Yes some kind of loop, thx

Comment: can you post a sample of the returned data?

Answer (score 1):

try using `map`

```
var array = $(data).map(function(){
    return new Date(this.StartTime.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);;
});
```

Or, to overwrite `StartTime`

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    element.StartTime = new Date(element.StartTime.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
});
```

Comment: how can I add that to the existing array? I need to use the array as a model for my view

Comment: thanks, which regex I can use to get MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM ? Thanks

Comment: from what? the `starttime` string? need more info.

Comment: Update the question with a example string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    var startDate= new Date(element.StartTime.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
});
```

would loop through all of the returned elements and extract the date.

You can have a second array, say `finalDates` and push the converted dates into that array as you loop.

Comment: can I add the converted values to the existing array? @tyler-sebastian thanks

Comment: I would need to know the structure of the returned data, but there's nothing stopping you from `data[index] = new Date(data[0].StartTime.match(...;` etc

Comment: your approach works only for the first element in the array, I'm not able to get data after the first element, I guess its because you have data[0]. This is the structure btw https://i.gyazo.com/d676e5a16ee1df54b2c229b184700094.png

Comment: @Laziale fixed, sorry

Answer (score 0):

My method uses a usual `for` statement, which is a little more verbose, but I prefer, as long is the most efficient way to traverse an array.
So, for each iteration, I got `data` at position `i` (`data[i]`), and stored the result in a temporary variable, called finalDate, and then finally push it to finalDates array. That's what you are looking for?

```
var finalDates = [];
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/Driver/GetDriverTrips',
    params: { id: id }
}).
success(function (data) {
    var finalDate;

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        finalDate = new Date(data[i].StartTime.match(/\d+/)[i] * 1);
        finalDates.push(finalDate);
    }
});
```